# Centered captionlabel above justified caption text

Tags: floats, horizontal-alignment, captions

I'd like to have the captionlabel (e.g. Figure 1) centered on a single line with the actual caption justified below. Something like this

[image: example]

As you can see, I've achieved what I want with the help of the `caption` package. However, this generates

```
LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.
```

for every figure. What am I doing wrong or how can I achieve this result without this error?

Something like

```
\usepackage[labelsep=newline,justification=centerfirst]
```

sort of achieves what I want and without errors, but the text is made to span the whole width of the textbox. (How do you call that, fully justified?) This often greatly decreases the legibility and I'd prefer not to use this option.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

%\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{center}{{\centering #1 #2}}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{center}{{\centering#1#2\\}#3}
\captionsetup{format=center,labelsep=none,justification=justified}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{}
    \caption{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin quis egestas massa, vitae imperdiet ligula. Curabitur porta luctus orci at congue. Cras luctus blandit velit, quis congue lectus ultricies vel. Quisque non eros ut ante tincidunt mattis sed quis nisi.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Does `\DeclareCaptionFormat{center}{{\hfil#1#2\hfil}#3}` works out for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\centerline` works:

\documentclass{article}

```
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}


\DeclareCaptionFormat{center}{{\centerline{#1#2}\\}#3}
\captionsetup{format=center,labelsep=none,justification=justified}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{}
    \caption{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin quis egestas massa, vitae imperdiet ligula. Curabitur porta luctus orci at congue. Cras luctus blandit velit, quis congue lectus ultricies vel. Quisque non eros ut ante tincidunt mattis sed quis nisi.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can define a `centerlabel` format in the following way:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\DeclareCaptionFormat{centerlabel}{%
  \sbox0{#3}%
  \makebox[\linewidth]{\scshape#1#2}\\
  \ifdim\wd0<\linewidth
    \makebox[\linewidth]{\unhbox0}%
  \else
    \unhbox0
  \fi
}
\captionsetup{format=centerlabel,labelsep=none,margin=2cm}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=3cm]{example-image}

\caption{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin quis egestas massa, 
vitae imperdiet ligula. Curabitur porta luctus orci at congue. Cras luctus blandit velit, 
quis congue lectus ultricies vel. Quisque non eros ut ante tincidunt mattis sed quis nisi.}

\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=3cm]{example-image}

\caption{Very short caption}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I too agree that `centerfirst` is the way to go; however, why redefine it? Also, @egreg, could you kindly explain the difference between the existing definition and this one and how this one works? I'd appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: @Amar I actually wasn't aware that a `centerfirst` style already existed! */hiding* The main difference is that here I check whether the caption text fits in the linewidth and center it if so: justifying a short caption with this format would give funny results.

Comment: Ya, `centerfirst` is the only thing I use almost exclusively in terms of caption justification. And the "funny results" you are talking about, I get those too, many a times; so, I just adjust `margin=x pt` inside `\captionsetup{}` for every such "funny occurrence". A lay-man's troubleshoot! :) I think, your `centerlabel` format will actually be very useful for me in such cases. Many thanks! Also, how did you figure out that `\wd0` controls the caption width? And is `\unbox0` used to spew out caption contents inside a box of width `\linewidth`?

Comment: @egerg What is this `/hiding` you mention in your comment above? Or is it there by mistake??

Comment: @Amar I was trying to hide my mistake of redefining `centerfirst`. `:-)` A kind of metacomment we use in chat.

Comment: could you please respond to my questions about the `\wid0` & `\unbox0` from earlier? Also, how to use `\hiding`? I googled it, but found nothing relevant.

Comment: @Amar I didn't figure out anything: with `\sbox0{#3}` I typeset the caption text in box register 0, so I can access its width (without line breaks) as `\wd0`; then I can decide whether centering it with `\makebox[\linewidth]{\unhbox0}` or simply make a paragraph, with `\unhbox0`. The command `\unhbox0` delivers the contents of box register 0, but unboxed, so it can be reflown.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I have removed the \\  used \hfil and \par in

```
\DeclareCaptionFormat and added width in the 
\captionsetup
```

Fullcode:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

%\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{center}{{\centering #1 #2}}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{center}{{\hfil\textsc{#1}#2\hfil}\par#3}
\captionsetup{format=center,labelsep=none,justification=justified, width=.8\textwidth}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{}
\caption{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin quis egestas massa, vitae imperdiet ligula. Curabitur porta luctus orci at congue. Cras luctus blandit velit, quis congue lectus ultricies vel. Quisque non eros ut ante tincidunt mattis sed quis nisi.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\DeclareCaptionFormat{center}{{\centerline{\textsc{#1}#2}\\}#3}
\captionsetup{format=center,labelsep=none,justification=justified}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{}
    \caption{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin quis egestas massa, vitae imperdiet ligula. Curabitur porta luctus orci at congue. Cras luctus blandit velit, quis congue lectus ultricies vel. Quisque non eros ut ante tincidunt mattis sed quis nisi.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: Justified, centered, small-caps]

Comment: This works, but as I stated I'd rather not use this option. I don't find the text as legible as my error generating example.

Comment: Missed that, edited answer.